# Como crear una columna calculada que me calcule variacion% de un registro y otro

Tags: sql, postgresql

Buenas tardes deseo insertar una columna calculada que me permita saber la variacion% de un dato a otro, use este tipo de consulta que encontre en el foro

```
    SELECT t.*, 100 * (close - close_a) / (close_a)
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
        (
            SELECT close
            FROM historical_prices t_ant
            WHERE t_ant.ticker = t_act.ticker AND t_ant.id < t_act.id
            ORDER BY Id DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) close_a
        FROM historical_prices t_act
        WHERE ticker = 'HGT'
        ORDER BY Fecha DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) t
    WHERE close_a IS NOT NULL;
```

Este funcionaria para que me muestre 1 solo registro con el criterio asignado que es SUJETO, sin embargo hay varios SUJETOS en la tabla, por lo que realizar la consulta para todos no se ejecuta, queda cargando el sistema.

Me gustaría que los resultados para cada registro queden en la tabla almacenados.

La tabla es:

```
CREATE TABLE public.historical_prices ( 
 id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT    nextval('historical_prices_idtest_seq'::regclass), 
change real, 
change_over_time real, 
change_percentage real, 
close real, 
date date, 
high real, 
low real, 
open real, 
ticker character varying(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default", 
uclose real, 
uhigh real, 
ulow real, 
uopen real, 
uvolume integer, 
volume integer, 
CONSTRAINT historical_prices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) )
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SO en español. Podrías poner más información de tu pregunta? por ejemplo la estructura de las tablas, el resultado deseado.

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿por qué quieres guardar en la BD esa columna calculada? ¿No es mejor calcularla *in situ* cuando la necesites. Ese puede ser un dato muerto, dormido en la BD para usarlo quién sabe cuando. La mayoría de datos calculados no deberían guardarse, podrías tener varios GB de información ahí guardada que quizá nunca uses, a no ser un sistema de estadística o algo así que los use constantemente.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Buenas tardes deseo este calculo para poder realizar análisis técnico, voy a calcular promedios,  variaciones para acciones, deseo que queden registrados para poder graficar, en la estructura de la tabla hay un campo con esa denominación, pero en algunos casos esta vacio.

Comment: CREATE TABLE public.historical_prices
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('historical_prices_idtest_seq'::regclass),
    change real,
    change_over_time real,
    change_percentage real,
    close real,
    date date,
    high real,
    low real,
    open real,
    ticker character varying(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    uclose real,
    uhigh real,
    ulow real,
    uopen real,
    uvolume integer,
    volume integer,
    CONSTRAINT historical_prices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

Answer (score 0):

No me quedó muy claro el cálculo que quieres hacer. Siempre ayuda que subas datos de ejemplo y el resultado deseado.

En esta query utilicé para el cálculo de la variación la "Window Function" lead() que en este caso retorna el valor de la próxima fila agrupando por ticker y ordenando por id ascendente. Como verás la última fila de cada grupo no tiene con quien comparar y por eso queda nulo el cálculo.

```
SELECT *, 
       100 * (lead(close, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY id ASC) - close) / close AS variacion
FROM historical_prices hp
ORDER BY ticker, id;
```

Para este conjunto de datos de ejemplo:

| id | ticker | close |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 10 |
| 2 | a | 5 |
| 3 | a | 15 |
| 4 | a | 20 |
| 5 | b | 1 |
| 6 | b | 6 |
| 7 | b | 7 |
| 8 | b | 100 |

La query retorna:

| id | ticker | close | variacion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 10 | -50 |
| 2 | a | 5 | 200 |
| 3 | a | 15 | 33.333333333333336 |
| 4 | a | 20 |  |
| 5 | b | 1 | 500 |
| 6 | b | 6 | 16.666666666666668 |
| 7 | b | 7 | 1328.5714285714287 |
| 8 | b | 100 |  |

Para actualizar la tabla la query sería la siguiente:

```
UPDATE historical_prices x
SET columna = aux.variacion

FROM 
(SELECT hp.id,
   100 * (lead(hp.close, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY hp.ticker ORDER BY hp.id ASC) - hp.close) / hp.close AS variacion
FROM historical_prices hp) AS aux

WHERE x.id = aux.id
```